# Template tag or filter

Tags: django, django-templates

hi all am trying do do this on the template `{% some_list |forloop.counter %}`and the return a value from the list i have this function that should do the trick but don't know how to put it all together here is the function below

```
def return_item(a_list,a_int):
    return a_list[a_int]
```

Comment: Have you read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **very** clear in [the django template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) docs how to do this:

```
@register.filter
def return_item(l, i)
    try:
        return l[i]
    except:
        return None
```

than:

```
{{ mylist|return_item:forloop.counter }}
```

Comment: @goliney so what you think i should use?

Comment: @user1711168 Timmy O'Mahony's snippet will do a trick. Using filters is most appropriate solution for your problem.